# Service that delivers fax to HTTP request

Tags: httpwebrequest, fax

is there any service which allows to rent a fax number and any fax which gets there gets posted to specific http address developer would provide? (hope i am clear enough) i know there are services posting fax to email, so i imagine sending it to the web server should be as well possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the Interfax inbound fax service. You can try this on their evaluation account.

To set this up, login to their control panel and select Preferences -> Incoming -> Advanced Options.  Set "Web Feedback Method", to "HTTP POST" and set "Web Feedback URL" to hold the specific address of your script.  Obviously, your web server needs to be publicly accessible for this to work.

Full documentation of the fields that are returned to your script in the callback is available in their article "[Receive incoming faxes via callback to a web application](http://www.interfax.net/en/node/698)"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite the answer you are looking for, but you could hook into an email address from a fax to email service, and then process the email.

Maybe running as a service on a web server?

We currently do this, using Sharepoint lists to process emails, and then put the attachments in a Sharepoint library.